# How to substr item in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi all I have following code: [my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-aryabhata-5hzbl)

In this scenario I am receiving some data from backend

```js
const fileName = 
  [ { id: 1, title: 'Armenia lorem ipsum 15 - Oct 30.pdf' } 
  , { id: 2, title: 'France lorem ipsum 16 - Nov 30.pdf'  } 
  , { id: 3, title: 'German lorem ipsum 17 - Dec 30.pdf'  } 
  , { id: 4, title: 'English lorem ipsum 18 - Jan 08.pdf' } 
  ]
```

I am counting if all titles chars sum is greater than 40 then I am hiding rest elements(in my case titles) and showing with numbers. That part works very good.

```js
let lengthCount = 0;
let maxIndex = 0;
const allowCharCount = 40;
const file = [];
const File = ({ data }) => {
  data.map((item, index) => {
    if (lengthCount <= allowCharCount) {
      maxIndex = index;
      file.push(item);
    }
    lengthCount = lengthCount + item.title.length;
  });

  let myFiles = file.map((perFile) => (
    <span key={perFile.id} className="skillItem">
      {perFile.title}
    </span>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="skillWrapper">
      <div>{myFiles}</div>
      {lengthCount < 20 ? null : (
        <div className="skillNumber">+{data.length - maxIndex - 1}</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

Now I am trying to get each elements title and transform them in this way: I need to get 5 chars from beginning then concatenate "..." and then concatenate 10 chars from the end.

I try to substr my title from the beginning and from the end but it not working

> "TypeError: titleFullName.substr is not a function"

here what I try:

```js
let titleFullName = file.map((item) => item.title);
let titleFullNameFirstPart = titleFullName.slice(0, 5);
const titleFullNameSecondPart = titleFullName.slice(10,titleFullName.length - 1);
const TitleName = titleFullNameFirstPart + "..." + titleFullNameSecondPart;
```

In the end, for each title I should get something like this, for example :

```
Armen... Oct 30.pdf
Franc... Nov 30.pdf
Germa... Dec 30.pdf
Engli... Jan 08.pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to transform the array, you should put the string transformation logic *inside* the `.map`, so that every item iterated over gets transformed. Your `titleFullNameSecondPart` also needs to be tweaked a bit, subtract 10 from the string length and pass it to `.slice` to get the last 10 characters.

```js
const fileName = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Armenia lorem ipsum 15 - Oct 30.pdf"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "France lorem ipsum 16 - Nov 30.pdf"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "German lorem ipsum 17 - Dec 30.pdf"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "English lorem ipsum 18 - Jan 08.pdf"
  }
];

const transformed = fileName.map((item) => {
  const titleFullName = item.title;
  let titleFullNameFirstPart = titleFullName.slice(0, 5);
  const titleFullNameSecondPart = titleFullName.slice(titleFullName.length - 10);
  const TitleName = titleFullNameFirstPart + "..." + titleFullNameSecondPart;
  return TitleName;
});

console.log(transformed);
```

Comment: I see, I think it works, but please help me to show each title in different boxes https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-wilbur-fl61f

Comment: When rendering, map over the `transformed`, so that each transformed item gets rendered separately. Or put all the transformation logic inside the `.map` done when returning the JSX